# How can I exclude ssh connections from being routed by WireGuard?

Tags: ssh, routing, wireguard

I have a VPS `server2` on which I have installed a server like WireGuard peer, up and running. I tested it from a mobile device and everything works fine. The config file is as below:

```
#Server2 Configuration
[Interface]
PrivateKey = $wgpk
ListenPort = $wgport
Address = 10.10.213.1/24
SaveConfig = false

[Peer]
PublicKey = $wgpub_peer
AllowedIPs = 10.10.231.3/32
PresharedKey = $preshared_key
PersistentKeepalive = $perkeep
```

Now on another VPS `server1` I want to connect to `server2` as client like peer. But activating WireGuard on `server1` immediately causes ssh connection lost and I no longer can ssh to my `server1` to investigate the issue. I tried to add a PostUp route so that I could exclude the ssh port 22 but did not solve my issue. The config for `server1` is as below:

```
#Server1 Configuration
[Interface]
PrivateKey = $wgpk_peer
Address = 10.10.231.3/32
DNS = [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
SaveConfig = false
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination $SERVER

[Peer]
PublicKey = $wgpub
PresharedKey = $preshared_key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = $SERVER2_public_ip:$wgport
PersistentKeepalive = $perkeep
```

The reason I am doing this is to protect my `server1` ip address and data by using a vpn connection. Please help if you have any idea how can I keep my ssh access to `server1`?

Comment: DNAT is NOT a route. Either add a static route in the main table for the particular server host, or use policy routing (ip rule) if you want to use the default gateway in the main table for all (tcp) dport 22 traffics.

Comment: Can you please do an answer I perform?

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Yan suggested, use policy routing or add a static route for your SSH connection.

To force Server1 to always use your main routing table for all SSH connections (instead of using the routing table WireGuard sets up), run the following policy routing command on Server1:

```
$ sudo ip rule add sport 22 table main priority 123
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to force Server1 to always use its current route to your local computer (instead of using the routing table WireGuard sets up), do the following to set up a static route for it:

First, determine the IP address of your current SSH session by running the following command on Server1:

```
$ ss -n sport 22
Netid  State   Recv-Q  Send-Q   Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port Process
tcp    ESTAB   0       0       10.200.200.123:22   198.51.100.234:12345
```

In the example above, the `Peer Address` column shows that your local computer's IP address is `198.51.100.234` from the perspective of Server1.

Next, determine the gateway that your SSH connection is currently using by running the following command on Server1:

```
$ ip route get 198.51.100.234 sport 22
198.51.100.234 via 10.200.200.1 dev eth0 src 10.200.200.123 uid 1000
    cache
```

In the example above, the `via 10.200.200.1 dev eth0` part of the output shows that your SSH connection is using `10.200.200.1` as the gateway from Server1, through Server1's `eth0` network interface.

Then, to force Server1 to always use this gateway for all connections from your current IP address, run the following command on Server1:

```
$ sudo ip route add 198.51.100.234 via 10.200.200.1 dev eth0
```

---

Note that if you reboot Server1, you'll have to re-run the above `ip route add` or `ip rule add` commands (so you may want to put them in a script that Server1 runs when it finishes booting up).